# Change in the imported function does not change the output while in python shell?

Tags: python

I am quite sure something like this must have been asked before but I couldn't word it properly to get to those questions. Here is my issue. Let's say I have a function called `square`, which returns square value of a given number.

```py
def square(number):
    return number*number
```

I store `square` function in `main.py` file. So in the python shell, I import and run the function like this:

```
>>> from main import square
>>> square(5)
```

Output is obviously `25` in this case. However, when I make changes in the function, for the sake an example, let's say:

```
def square(number):
    return number*number*2
```

and import and run in **previously opened** python shell again. The result remains the same (i.e. `25`). However, it should be `50`. The changes take effect if the close and reopen the python shell. Is there a way to overcome this without opening a new python shell everytime for testing. I have tested this in python `2.7.14` and `3.8.3`.

Comment: `import` loads the module into memory, it's not read from the file every time you call the function. To reload it, see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/437589/3001761.

Comment: Thank you for the comments. They are indeed helpful. I checked the accepted solution of the answer. Its for python3, is there any python2 solution?

Comment: There are answers there for many versions, keep scrolling!

Comment: Ah. Got it `reload` module. Thanks.

Comment: Votes reflect the usefulness to future visitors, not the amount of work you put in.